# Unable to connect to update server when installing

Tags: smartface.io

I downloaded the installer and run it, but I get a message telling me to check my internet connection. My connection works fine, but I suspect there might be a proxy problem. Does anybody know how to remedy this?

Comment: If there is any proxy it is normal to see this kind of error. You should set your proxy on login screen.

Comment: Well, I suppose there will be a login screen when I have installed, but it's during the installation that this happens

Comment: Can you try to download Smartface from this link : license.smartface.io/download/SmartfaceAppStudio.exe

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, but today when I started the installer (the same installer I downloaded two days ago) and there was no error message. I think the problem was caused by the `smarface.io` server(s).

Thus, when you get this error message while installing `smartface`:

> "Unable to connect to update server. Please check you internet connection and try again. #1"

Just wait for a day or two and start the installer again. The error message will disappear!

I have a code improvement suggestion for `smartface.io`:

I hope the error message never occurs in the future, but if it does you should correct the spelling: the word "you" in the error message is incorrect. It should be "your".